# SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE inconsistent results with perl DBI

Tags: mysql, perl, plsql, dbi

Piping "SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE foo" into mysql results include the complete procedure definition in a column labeled "Create Procedure". However,

> $dbh->selectrow_hashref("SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE foo");

results in $ref->{'Create Procedure'} being undef, with other columns correctly populated.
Both executed on the same machine with the same credentials.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you would see if the user you connect as doesn't have permission to see the procedure.  Try using the same user on the command line and I'd guess you will see NULL for the Create Procedure column.

You appear to need select privilege on mysql.proc to see procedure bodies.